# How can I show a element on my site when hovered with only JS?

Tags: javascript, css, web, hover

EDIT:

Hi, I would like to know how could I show a little X or remove icon when a user hovers over the inbox

I tried to hide the remove icon first and then add this effect to a `<p>` element `:hover {display:block;}` ,I don't know what I did wrong but it didn't work

http://jsbin.com/zijewohoru/1/edit?html,css,output

Is there anyway I could do it with JS or would it be a lot easier to do it with CSS?

Comment: People that downvote should leave a comment as to why they downvoted. Since they won't do it, I will. @common you need to show us the code you did. You need to go into a detailed explanation as to what exactly you want, what you tried. Putting a link to an external website isn't sufficient.

Comment: @Grimbode thank you, I will do it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this is what you are looking for.

```
/* Hide icon by default */
.box i {
  display: none;
}

/* Show icon on containing element hover */
.box:hover i {
  display: block;
}
```

For a fade-in transition, this would work.

```
.box i {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
}

.box:hover i {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I was actually looking to do this effect with JS, but CSS works too!

Could you tell me is there anyway to do a smooth hover transit effect?

Comment: @common do you mean like a transition or animation effect? Like fade-in?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```css
.box:hover > i {
  display: block;
}
.box > i {
  display: none;
}
```